# Highcharts Export Renderer Image - Only SVG visible

Tags: javascript, highcharts, export

I am using the renderer when exporting to try and add a logo to the graph, it generates perfectly when i export to SVG but if i try png/jpeg/pdf i get a completely blank image (absolutely nothing appears). If i use any other type of renderer such as text or shapes everything works perfectly, it is JUST with the renderer of an image therefore i believe it has to do with the conversion that takes place. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using the following plug-ins:
- export-csv (to allow CSV and XLS)
- jspdf (enable PDF option)
- jspdf.plugin.addimage (to allow image to be created in PDF)
- canvas-tools ( to draw images as PNG, JPEG, SVG)
- highcharts-export-clientside (to remove server dependency)

Comment: That sounds like path to the image is relative, while should be absolute. Any chance to show some live demo with that issue?

Comment: Unfortunately it is a private project and i am unable to reproduce the code out of this environment, i know asking here without actual code is a long shot.

Comment: There may be a couple of issues. First, as I said, make sure you have absolute path for the image. Then if you are not using Highcharts exporting server, make sure your solution waits until all images are loaded, otherwise you may not render them.

Answer (score 1):

To Export High charts to png You can use Html2Canvas library, which can take a screenshot of your high charts and generate a PNG Image.
using Html2Canvas its not possible then you can use [CANVG](https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg) library,which is convert your svg element to PNG Image.